# Как применить шифр Цезаря к точке и запятой?

Tags: python

Пишу программу с проверкой пароля.
Использую алгоритм Цезаря, для дешифровки, всё работает, но только не с точкой и запятой. Вот код самого дешифратора:

```
alfavit =  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя.,.,01234567890123456789'
smeshenie = 1
message = line
itog = ''

for i in message:
    mesto = alfavit.find(i) #ищем индекс первого вхождения в строку
    new_mesto = mesto - smeshenie #задаём новый индекс
    if i in alfavit:
        itog += alfavit[new_mesto]  #задаем значения в итог
    else:
        itog += i
print ('Сообщение в расшифрованном виде: ',itog)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alfavit =  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя.,.,01234567890123456789'
```

а ничего, что вы точку и запятую 2 раза указали?

```
ыьэюя.,.,0123456
```

как думаете какой символ будет получаться при кодировании? :)

Comment: так там и алфавит 2 раза повторяется.

Comment: А я всё по два раза делал, просто в инете алгоритм смотрел, чёт я запутался в общем тогда. Спасибо за помощь ошибку нашёл, уже просто спать рубит.